# The best way to store picture with SQLite and nHibernate

Tags: c#, sqlite, nhibernate

The application is written in C#. It uses nHibernate and SQLite and runs on Windows. I should store pictures and bind them to a user.

So far, I don't really know what is the best way to store the pictures. If I decide to store the path of the picture and save the image in a directory, I'll have problems as soon as the directory or the file is renamed or moved. In the other hand, storing image as BLOB in SQLite is slow as I have to "cast" the image into a bytes array before storing and when I retrieve, I have to set the bytes array into an image.

What is the recommended way for this?

Comment: [Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html)

Comment: One thing I did in the past was create a "RootFolder" table (RFKey, RFName) with a row like "1001, 'c:\myfolder\'".  The my table with image-FILENAMES had a RelativePath and a FK to RootFolder.RFKey.   a row in here would look like "mysecondfolder\myfile.png, 1001".  This way I could "move files" and only had to change one value in the RootFolder table (as long as the relative paths stayed the same).  That project was always moving files around...(keeping the relative path names in tact)...but updating the first part of a million rows with a string-replace was brutal.  Just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an image user type for this purpose. With it, you just pass the Image object, not its bytes: http://weblogs.asp.net/ricardoperes/archive/2009/09/17/nhibernate-image-user-type.aspx.